# Как сделать уменьшение шрифта если текст не помещается TextBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Как сделать "сжатие" текста, если он не помещается в поле.

Допустим у меня есть ТекстБокс для ввода ФИО, переносить нельзя, поэтому нужно сделать так, что бы при большом тексте, шрифт уменьшался

Comment: Оберните ваш текст в ViewBox

Comment: можно подробнее?

Comment: [How to use the ViewBox in WPF](https://www.wpftutorial.net/ViewBox.html)

Comment: Он растягивает или сокращает сам элемент. Текст же по прежнему выходит за рамки

Comment: Разве: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFD33.gif ?

Comment: хммм, с текстблоком работает, а с текстбоксом нет. Спасибо за помощь. Если оставите исправленный ответ, буду рад принять его

Comment: И если можете скиньте код ксамл, у меня не получается с помощью TextAligment с центра начинать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы не уродовать сам контрол и менять только размер шрифта в нем, можно написать простой конвертер:

```
class AdaptiveFontSizeConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)values[0];
        var dpiX = 96.0 * VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(textBox).DpiScaleX; // .NET 4.6.2+
        var formattedText =
            new FormattedText(
                textBox.Text,
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                textBox.FlowDirection,
                new Typeface(
                    textBox.FontFamily,
                    textBox.FontStyle,
                    textBox.FontWeight,
                    textBox.FontStretch),
                textBox.FontSize,
                textBox.Foreground,
                dpiX);
        var fontSize = textBox.FontSize * textBox.ViewportWidth / formattedText.Width;
        if (parameter == null) return fontSize;
        var maxSize = (double)parameter;
        return Math.Min(fontSize, maxSize);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Используем:

```
<Grid Margin="5" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <c:AdaptiveFontSizeConverter x:Key="conv"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBox.FontSize>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource conv}">
                <MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
                    <s:Double>12</s:Double>
                </MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                <Binding Path="Text" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBox.FontSize>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

По сути сам конвертер принимает только ссылку на TextBox, но т.к. нам надо реагировать на изменение текста в нем, то делаем мультиконвертер и передаем ссылку на свойство Text вторым объектом (но в коде этот второй объект не используется). Дальше все просто — измеряем ширину текста внутри контрола и вычисляем конечный размер шрифта. Ну и добавил еще параметром возможность указания максимального размера шрифта, чтобы контрол не становился уж очень большим когда в нем мало символов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Решение не плохое. Но ведь такое решение сильно влияет на производительность так?

Comment: С чего вы взяли? Вы уже реально столкнулись с проблемой производительности? Тут как бы GUI, поэтому производительность здесь малокритична, пользователь в любом случае вводит текст медленнее, чем выполняется этот метод, да даже опрос клавиатуры происходит медленнее, поэтому проблем быть не должно. Но с другой стороны, я бы не стал использовать это решение чисто с эстетической стороны, всё должно выглядеть красиво, но и заниматься красотой должен не программист, а дизайнер, поэтому именно он должен найти лучшее решение — может как-то увеличить поле ввода, разрешить многострочный ввод или т.п.